# "Reply to and Forward Emails Right from Salesforce"

Tags: email, lightning-experience

I'm looking at this here...

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_email_replyforward.htm

Apparently the Past Activity section in Lightning is supposed to present these nice Reply All / Reply / Forward options. We're only seeing this sporadically in our org (some users see it but it doesn't work, most users don't see it at all). I can't seem to find any details on what I might be doing that causes these actions to disappear. Any ideas?

Comment: please share screens of cases that this works and cases that it doesn't work

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I raised a support case around this. Below is the reply:

> Regarding your concern, the Reply, Reply All and Forward buttons
>   appear when your own email address is the "From" address. As
>   per your screenshot, only the email that has "You" as the sender has
>   such buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is correct. Has anyone else encountered this?