# How to get missing Buttons "Reply", "Reply All", "Forward" on Emails at the Activity Tab in Lightning Experience?

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, send-email, global-actions

I'm working on hundreds of different orgs. Some of them have those buttons, other not. How can I get them on all orgs? (In the screenshots see right side in the bottom of each email.)

**BAD ORGS**

[image]

**GOOD ORGS**

[image]

**What have I tried so far?**

**A) I found https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000257353&type=1**

> If, however, the 'Reply,' 'Reply All,' or 'Forward'  buttons are not
>   present on the records in the Activity timeline, the 'Send Email'
>   global action may not have been added as a Global Action on the page
>   layout of the the entity in question.

I have a "Send Email" Global Action on the layout. A small difference might be, that I have renamed the out-of-the-box Global Action "Send Email" now having a slightly differen API name elfBCSendEmail instead of just SendEmail.

**B) This seems also not to be a solution:**  ["Reply to and Forward Emails Right from Salesforce"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171778/reply-to-and-forward-emails-right-from-salesforce)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what led me to try this, but adding the Send Email action to our Global Publisher Layout did the trick for me.

Comment: For whoever is searching for the answer to this, adding to the global publisher layout did the trick for me as well

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks for the help and tip :)